# Exiting lockTaskMode in android shows lock screen

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, android-screen-pinning

In my android app, the user should be restricted from navigating away from an activity while a certain process happens on the backend. For this, I use `startLockTask()` in the activity when the process starts, and when the process ends I call `stopLockTask()`.

Currently the app runs on a device where there's no device owner set, so screen pinning is activated, not lock task mode.

It seems that if a lock screen is configured on the device, upon calling `stopLockTask` the device always shows the lock screen. Why is that? can't I just unpin?  Is this the normal behaviour? Can I disable that?

I tried with a [sample app](https://github.com/mrugacz95/kiosk) which just starts/stops lock task mode with button presses and it seems the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps anyone -

Turns out that this is a behaviour that can be controlled via settings, it's actually a feature.
On my Samsung device:

Settings -> Security -> Other security settings -> Pin windows -> disable “Ask for pattern before unpinning”